# How to create a logout dialog box using jquery mobile?

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am new to jqueryMobile. I want to create a a dialog box on click of logout image.

In the application I have a logout image on click of which it should create a dialog popup for asking "do you really want to logout?" with two buttons yes and no. As I'm new to jqueryMobile I dont know how to make it. Please help me with this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think this may help to you..
Check this they have displayed two buttons with one editbox, you can modify as per your requirements
http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-SimpleDialog/demos/string.html